# Can I access Bank Statement lines using the XERO-api?

Tags: xero-api

I'm not an accountant, I know almost nothing about XERO.
BUT, I did successfully follow these [instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYRYlXhdxGU) and now have my Linux box talking to my XERO demo account.

**Objective:**

My goal is to autonomously parse bank account activity.  I want the script to be the first to spot new incoming payments, long before accounting wakes up.

**Observation:**

XERO seems to consider "Bank statement lines" and "Transactions" two separate things.
I can access "Transactions" with a line like `$apiResponse = $apiInstance->getBankTransactionsWithHttpInfo($xeroTenantId);`
But I couldn't immediately find a method for "Bank statement lines", worse: I found [this page](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/bankstatements)

**Questions:**

- Is  [this page](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/bankstatements) up-to-date, are "Bank statement lines" not accessible through the XERO-api?
- Would anyone be able to recommend another platform, ideally as cheap as XERO, which does allow access to "Bank statement lines" through their api?

Comment: Did you find a way around this?

Comment: I am trying to do this too. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is currently possible to access Statement Lines or do any reconciliation via the Xero API.

Their API seems a bit neglected to me, which is a shame because it's a great product.